# Magento product count shows wrong?

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I am new in magento and the problem is the following:

Suppose I select one product and add to the shopping cart and go to checkout page and fill all details then place the order,

Everything works fine but the problem is it displays the product count as 2, not 1.

I am using this code:

```
$items = $order->getAllItems();
echo count($items);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, use:

```
$items=$order->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Background: eg. if you have a configurable product, magento technically stores both the main and variation.